# How should I write the JOIN clause to make it work well?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm doing Q4 (Find the titles of all movies not reviewed by Chris Jackson. ) from SQL Movie-Rating Query Exercises Extras and I don't know why this code doesn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT movie.title
FROM movie
        INNER JOIN rating ON movie.mid = rating.mID
        INNER JOIN reviewer ON rating.rid = reviewer.rid
WHERE rating.mid NOT IN (SELECT rating.mid FROM rating WHERE rating.rid = (SELECT reviewer.rid FROM reviewer WHERE reviewer.name = 'Chris Jackson') )
```

Output:

```
title
Gone with the Wind
Snow White
Avatar
```

This output doesn't include movies that ARE in movie table but ARE NOT in rating table. So I suspect maybe this has something to do with JOIN clause.

TABLES:
Movie

```
mID title                   year    director
101 Gone with the Wind      1939    Victor Fleming
102 Star Wars               1977    George Lucas
103 The Sound of Music      1965    Robert Wise
104 E.T.                    1982    Steven Spielberg
105 Titanic                 1997    James Cameron
106 Snow White              1937    <null>
107 Avatar                  2009    James Cameron
108 Raiders of the Lost Ark 1981    Steven Spielberg
```

Reviewer

```
rID name
201 Sarah Martinez
202 Daniel Lewis
203 Brittany Harris
204 Mike Anderson
205 Chris Jackson
206 Elizabeth Thomas
207 James Cameron
208 Ashley White
```

Rating

```
rID mID stars   ratingDate
201 101 2       2011-01-22
201 101 4       2011-01-27
202 106 4       <null>
203 103 2       2011-01-20
203 108 4       2011-01-12
203 108 2       2011-01-30
204 101 3       2011-01-09
205 103 3       2011-01-27
205 104 2       2011-01-22
205 108 4       <null>
206 107 3       2011-01-15
206 106 5       2011-01-19
207 107 5       2011-01-20
208 104 3       2011-01-02
```

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Insert images/links using edit functions.

Comment: Look into `left join` behaviour

Comment: What is your question? Please edit to clarify. Do you want to know why the code doesn't do what you expect? Then you have to clearly tell us what that is. Do you want to know how to write the query, per your title? Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to include the tag for the DBMS you're using when you ask an SQL question, though I think in this case you can get away without doing so.

Comment: One way, not necessarily the best, would be to add a UNION clause to include unreviewed movies: `UNION SELECT movie.title FROM movie WHERE movie.mid NOT IN (SELECT rating.mid FROM rating)`.  The cost of this depends in part on the relative sizes of the movie and review tables, and whether the optimizer can deduce that it doesn't need duplicates in the output from the inner SELECT, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you must use [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) and then then use `GROUP BY movie.mid, movie.title` and put the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT movie.title
FROM movie
LEFT JOIN rating ON movie.mid = rating.mID
LEFT JOIN reviewer ON rating.rid = reviewer.rid
GROUP BY movie.mid, movie.title
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN reviewer.name = 'Chris Jackson' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a519a62dfbe6395799c6cab0a08a2bd5).
Results:

```
> | title              |
> | :----------------- |
> | Avatar             |
> | Gone with the Wind |
> | Snow White         |
> | Star Wars          |
> | Titanic            |
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use aggregation, I would recommend `NOT EXISTS` for this purpose.  It is close to the phrasing of the logic you want:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM movie m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM rating r JOIN
                       reviewer re
                       ON r.rid = re.rid
                  WHERE m.mid = r.mID AND
                        re.name = 'Chris Jackson'
                 );
```

There should simply be no comparison from a performance perspective.  This should have much better performance.

Comment: @forpas . . . The second query gets all movies not reviewed by "Chris Jackson", so it would appear to answer the question.  And yes, I think that `not exists` is faster than the equivalent joins plus aggregation on all the data.